# redirect website while making backup

Tags: mysql, apache-2.4, lamp, incrontab

I use `incron` to create backups for a website, and I like to redirect all requests to an other site when/while my scripts are running.

What I have done so far...
`incron` runs some scripts every time I update files in `/var/www`.
First it adds some entries to a database.
Then it makes an gnu incremental backup with `tar`. After that it uses `mysqldump` for extraction of the database and `gzip` for compression the sql file.

Now I like to add statistics to my database too.
I was thinking of adding  `/var/log/apache2/access.log` to `incron`.

But this way I can mess up my database backups. I need a save way to extract my database without shutting down `apache` nor `mysql`. I could block write access on mysql but my website will still be available and I cant update statistics in the mean time without getting an error.

Is there a way to redirect all access of one domain, as long my scripts are running ? Maybe `mod_rewrite` with some `if`, but which arguments I have to use then ?

to be hornest, I have no clue how to archive this and I will be pleased to hear some advice.

Apache 2.4.10
MySQL 5.7
Debian Jessie

Answer (score 0):

> I need a save way to extract my database without shutting down Apache
>   nor MySQL.

I think you just want to **avoid any modifications** to your database **during the backup**, in order to keep it consistent. You might be just over-complicating this with your redirecting scenario, if everything is on a single database. MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual for [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) helps us here:

> [`--lock-tables, -l`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables)
>
> For each dumped database, lock all tables to be dumped before dumping
>   them. The tables are locked with `READ LOCAL` to permit concurrent
>   inserts in the case of `MyISAM` tables. For transactional tables such as
>   `InnoDB`, `--single-transaction` is a much better option than
>   `--lock-tables` because it does not need to lock the tables at all.
>
> Because `--lock-tables` locks tables for each database separately, this
>   option does not guarantee that the tables in the dump file are
>   logically consistent between databases. Tables in different databases
>   may be dumped in completely different states.
>
> [`--single-transaction`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction)
>
> This option sets the transaction isolation mode to REPEATABLE READ and
>   sends a [START TRANSACTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) SQL statement to the server before dumping
>   data. It is useful only with transactional tables such as `InnoDB`,
>   because then it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time
>   when [START TRANSACTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) was issued without blocking any applications.
>
> When using this option, you should keep in mind that only `InnoDB` tables are 
>   dumped in a consistent state. For example, any `MyISAM` or `MEMORY` tables 
>   dumped while using this option may still change state.